# Can't run detox tests on iOS

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I've searched all related here but nothing works.

I'm trying to use Detox with Mocha but it can't run the tests, the log when I run `detox test -l trace`:

```
...

detox[12558] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] [...] launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 1F09B4A8-C207-4E91-9BFF-87183260FFAC log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/giovani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F09B4A8-C207-4E91-9BFF-87183260FFAC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31C46970-641E-4AEA-94F1-279D45AF1780/[...].app"'
detox[12614] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onLaunchApp({ bundleId: [...],
  deviceId: '1F09B4A8-C207-4E91-9BFF-87183260FFAC',
  launchArgs:
   { detoxServer: 'ws://localhost:56360',
     detoxSessionId: 'ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba' },
  pid: 12614 })
detox[12558] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox[12558] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=isReady (sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba)
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba)
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}"
detox[12558] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterAll()
detox[12558] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.

detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=tester not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba)
detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully

  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.




detox[12557] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration ios.sim.debug --loglevel trace --grep :android: --invert --artifacts-location "artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2019-08-07 22-28-07Z" "e2e"
```

At row `detox[12558] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=ff40ffaf-dfa6-d1de-b668-47dad352a1ba` hangs for a while;

My script is:

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/mocha/adapter');

before(async () => {
  await detox.init(config, {launchApp: false});
  await device.launchApp({permissions: {location: 'always', notifications: 'YES'}});
});

beforeEach(async function () {
  await adapter.beforeEach(this);
});

afterEach(async function () {
  await adapter.afterEach(this);
});

after(async () => {
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

I just found out when I switch `await detox.init(config, {launchApp: false});` to await detox.init(config, {launchApp: false, reuse: true});`, open a simulator, set debug mode and rerun detox it worked but the test seems not synchronize with the app so failed before app starts.

I've done some search but I can't make this work so if anyone passed by this please help me with it.

Here my current versions of the things:

```
mocha: 6.2.0
node: 10.8.0
react-native: 0.57.8
Detox: 14.0.0
Xcode: 10.3
macOS: 10.14.6
```

Comment: When you run your test normally, what do you see in the simulator? Do you see your app launch, hang in splash screen, then eventually exit?

Comment: Opening the simulator I see my app launching, not hanging on splash screen. When the test fails, the app doesn't exit

Comment: Then follow the various docs on how to debug synchronization issues.